# 500 Server error in Configuration page

Tags: error, ce-1.8.1.0

I started having a 500 Server Error in Magento's configuration page. The rest of the website works ok. I turned DeveloperMode on and I got the following message:

```
Method "addJqueryLibrary" is not defined in "Magentothem_Upsellslider_Model_Layout_Generate_Observer"

#0 /home/webiste/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1340): Mage::throwException('Method "addJque...')
#1 /home/webiste/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Magentothem_Upsellslider_Model_Layout_Generate_Observer), 'addJqueryLibrar...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#2 /home/webiste/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#3 /home/webiste/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(351): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#4 /home/webiste/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#5 /home/webiste/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#6 /home/webiste/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/ConfigController.php(95): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#7 /home/webiste/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController->editAction()
#8 /home/webiste/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#9 /home/webiste/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#10 /home/webiste/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#11 /home/webiste/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 /home/webiste/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#13 {main}
```

Any body seen this before of know how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this has been discussed on StackOverflow

[Magento empty blank product page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21866716/magento-empty-blank-product-page)

The accepted answer reads:

It looks like the module `Magentothem Upsellslider` is broken. If you installed the module from somewhere else, contact the creator and tell them it isn't working. In the meantime, uninstall it by removing the file `app/code/etc/modules/Magentothem_Upsellslider.xml` and clear your cache.

If this is your module, you seem to be trying to call a non-existent function `addJqueryLibrary` in your observer. Perhaps you have a typo... should it be `addJQueryLibrary`?

Comment: the extension's code hasn't been updated or changed. If so, what could cause this?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the module & clearing your cache as per the article on SO?

Comment: Yes, it's the module that causes this. I'll try to re-install it or contact the creator. I just don't understand how the code could change without any action or permission... Thank you

Comment: Well, it could be as a result of conflict with another extension. Have you made any source code changes recently? The SO post mentions that the OP actually disabled another module & then the initial one worked.